# How to substract string correctly?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, substring, nsrange

i've got two strings in two objects:

```
&lt;div align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8448/7882675644_76605a2a3d_b.jpg&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;

&lt;img src=&quot;http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8425/7881940452_d2a8e898a3_o.png&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;
```

And i'm trying to substract link to image.

i get link by using object method:

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:description];

int left = [string rangeOfString:@"http://"].location;

int right = 0;

if ([string rangeOfString:@".jpg"].location != NSNotFound) {
    right = [string rangeOfString:@".jpg"].location;
}
else if ([string rangeOfString:@".png"].location != NSNotFound){
    right = [string rangeOfString:@".png"].location;
}


NSString *sub = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(left, right)];

NSLog(@"%@",sub);
```

but the problem is when i print what i substract:

```
2012-08-29 18:53:30.716 MyApple[56335:c07] http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8448/7882675644_76605a2a3d_b.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></di
2012-08-29 18:53:30.717 MyApple[56335:c07] http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8425/7881940452_d2a8e898a3_o.png" bord
```

IMO i substract from http:// to .jpg or .png, but it's not working correctly.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of `NSMakeRange()` is the *length*, so you probably need

```
NSString *sub = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(left, right - left)];
```

You should also take a look at `NSRegularExpression`!

Comment: @TomaszSzulc: Yes, it was just a trivial mistake that often happens. - But you should "accept" the answer anyway to get the question removed from the "unanswered" list.